# How can a neural network handle different image sizes, when performing deep dreaming using image pyramids?

Tags: neural-networks, convolutional-neural-networks, inception, deepdreaming, deepdream

I read that image pyramids are used for deep dreaming. The image is feed through the network multiple times and is rescaled during the process, to capture features in different scales. But how can the neural network handle the different input sizes? Are the inputs padded with zeros to match the network input size?

Comment: Can you show where you saw this?

Comment: @user253751 Yes, sure. https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=6rVrh5gnpwk at timestamp 6:31.

Comment: I see. Perhaps they were using the convolutional part of the network, which is size-independent